# Push badge persist

Tags: titanium-mobile

the push badge stays on the app what ever I did! even the push notification function well, and I do open the app normally, but the BADGE stay all time there and never goes away.
I did try this method below (which didn't help)

```
Titanium.UI.iPhone.appBadge = 0;
```

Comment: some context would help ! Are you programing in witch language. Witch framework. Etc ...

Answer (score 0):

After reading your question I guess you want to reset the app badge displayed over your app icon. I think you are using `Cloud.PushNotifications` to send push notification. If so it will store the number of badges on the ACS which will be updated each time you call the `Cloud.PushNotifications.notify` method and it will be set to app icon each time you receive the push.

To reset the badge in ACS try the following

```
Cloud.PushNotifications.resetBadge({
    device_token: device_token //Give your device token here
}, function (e) {
    if (e.success) {
        Ti.UI.iPhone.setAppBadge(0); //Resetting the badge in device
    }
    else {
        Ti.API.error(e);
    }
});
```

Now when you receive a new notification the badge will be set to  (depending upon the value of badge property in push payload received).

Hope it helped you.

Comment: I do use Urban airship modul.. and NOT cloud. Push. any other help U may suggest_ ?